# Fail with Code translate(from Python to C#)

Tags: python, c#, tuples, translate

I need help translating Python code. I try all my best. but fail all the time, and I need to submit a job tomorrow.

The program searches for the minimum sum of the elements of the path from the center of the array to one of the countries, moves left, right, up, down, diagonally it is impossible, and it is also impossible to come to those points that have already been.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    public struct Point
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;

        public Point(int x, int y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }
    }

    static int n, m;
    static int[][] matrix;

    static Dictionary<Point, Point> points;
    static int[][] recalculatedMatrix;

    static void Main()
    {
        ReadInput();

        points = new Dictionary<Point, Point>();

        recalculatedMatrix = new int[n][];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            recalculatedMatrix[i] = new int[m];
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                recalculatedMatrix[i][j] = int.MaxValue;
                points[new Point(i, j)] = new Point(-1, -1);
            }
        }

        int nowPointX = m / 2;
        int nowPointY = n / 2;

        recalculatedMatrix[nowPointY][nowPointX] = matrix[nowPointY][nowPointX];
        points[new Point(nowPointY, nowPointX)] = new Point(nowPointY, nowPointX);

        int layer = n / 2 - 1;

        while (layer >= 0)
        {
            FillingLine(layer, layer, layer + 1);
            FillingColumn(layer, layer, layer + 1);
            FillingColumn(n - layer - 1, layer, n - layer - 2);
            FillingLine(n - layer - 1, layer, n - layer - 2);

            if (recalculatedMatrix[layer][layer + 1] < recalculatedMatrix[layer + 1][layer])
            {
                recalculatedMatrix[layer][layer] = recalculatedMatrix[layer][layer + 1] + matrix[layer][layer];
                points[new Point(layer, layer)] = new Point(layer, layer + 1);
                RecountColumnValues(layer, layer + 1, n - layer - 1);
            }
            else
            {
                recalculatedMatrix[layer][layer] = recalculatedMatrix[layer + 1][layer] + matrix[layer][layer];
                points[new Point(layer, layer)] = new Point(layer + 1, layer);
                RecountRowValues(layer, layer + 1, n - layer - 1);
            }

            if (recalculatedMatrix[n - layer - 1][layer + 1] < recalculatedMatrix[n - layer - 2][layer])
            {
                recalculatedMatrix[n - layer - 1][layer] = recalculatedMatrix[n - layer - 1][layer + 1] + matrix[n - layer - 1][layer];
                points[new Point(n - layer - 1, layer)] = new Point(n - layer - 1, layer + 1);
                RecountColumnValues(layer, n - layer - 2, layer);
            }
            else
            {
                recalculatedMatrix[n - layer - 1][layer] = recalculatedMatrix[n - layer - 2][layer] + matrix[n - layer - 1][layer];
                points[new Point(n - layer - 1, layer)] = new Point(n - layer - 2, layer);
                RecountRowValues(n - layer - 1, layer + 1, n - layer - 1);
            }

            if (recalculatedMatrix[n - layer - 1][n - layer - 2] < recalculatedMatrix[n - layer - 2][n - layer - 1])
            {
                recalculatedMatrix[n - layer - 1][n - layer - 1] = recalculatedMatrix[n - layer - 1][n - layer - 2] + matrix[n - layer - 1][n - layer - 1];
                points[new Point(n - layer - 1, n - layer - 1)] = new Point(n - layer - 1, n - layer - 2);
                RecountColumnValues(n - layer - 1, n - layer - 2, layer);
            }
            else
            {
                recalculatedMatrix[n - layer - 1][n - layer - 1] = recalculatedMatrix[n - layer - 2][n - layer - 1] + matrix[n - layer - 1][n - layer - 1];
                points[new Point(n - layer - 1, n - layer - 1)] = new Point(n - layer - 2, n - layer - 1);
                RecountRowValues(n - layer - 1, n - layer - 2, layer);
            }

            layer -= 1;

            int minWay = GetMinWay();
            Console.WriteLine("Minimal way: " + minWay);

            var minPath = GetMinPath();
            Console.WriteLine("Minimal path: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                {
                    if (j != m - 1)
                    {
                        if (minPath.Contains(new Point(i, j)))
                        {
                            Console.Write($"-{matrix[i][j]} ");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.Write($"{matrix[i][j]} ");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (minPath.Contains(new Point(i, j)))
                        {
                            Console.Write($"-{matrix[i][j]} ");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.Write($"{matrix[i][j]}\n");
                        }
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            
        }

        static void ReadInput()
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("input.txt");
            string[] firstLine = lines[0].Split();
            n = int.Parse(firstLine[0]);
            m = int.Parse(firstLine[1]);

            matrix = new int[n][];

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                string[] row = lines[i + 1].Split();
                matrix[i] = new int[m];
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                {
                    matrix[i][j] = int.Parse(row[j]);
                }
            }
        }

        static void FillingLine(int row, int layer, int previousLine)
        {
            int nowPointX = 0;
            int nowPointY = 0;
            int minDistance = int.MaxValue;

            for (int elemFromLine = layer; elemFromLine < m - layer; elemFromLine++)
            {
                int recalculatedValue = recalculatedMatrix[previousLine][elemFromLine] + matrix[row][elemFromLine];
                if (recalculatedValue < minDistance)
                {
                    minDistance = recalculatedValue;
                    nowPointX = elemFromLine;
                    nowPointY = row;
                }
            }

            recalculatedMatrix[nowPointY][nowPointX] = minDistance;
            points[new Point(nowPointY, nowPointX)] = new Point(previousLine, nowPointX);

            for (int i = nowPointX + 1; i < n - layer - 1; i++)
            {
                if (recalculatedMatrix[row][i - 1] < recalculatedMatrix[previousLine][i])
                {
                    recalculatedMatrix[row][i] = recalculatedMatrix[row][i - 1] + matrix[row][i];
                    points[new Point(row, i)] = new Point(row, i - 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    recalculatedMatrix[row][i] = recalculatedMatrix[previousLine][i] + matrix[row][i];
                    points[new Point(row, i)] = new Point(previousLine, i);
                }
            }

            for (int i = nowPointX - 1; i >= layer; i--)
            {
                if (recalculatedMatrix[row][i + 1] < recalculatedMatrix[previousLine][i])
                {
                    recalculatedMatrix[row][i] = recalculatedMatrix[row][i + 1] + matrix[row][i];
                    points[new Point(row, i)] = new Point(row, i + 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    recalculatedMatrix[row][i] = recalculatedMatrix[previousLine][i] + matrix[row][i];
                    points[new Point(row, i)] = new Point(previousLine, i);
                }
            }
        }

        static void FillingColumn(int column, int layer, int previousColumn)
        {
            int nowPointX = 0;
            int nowPointY = 0;
            int minDistance = int.MaxValue;

            for (int elemFromColumn = layer; elemFromColumn < m - layer; elemFromColumn++)
            {
                int recalculatedValue = recalculatedMatrix[elemFromColumn][previousColumn] + matrix[elemFromColumn][column];
                if (recalculatedValue < minDistance)
                {
                    minDistance = recalculatedValue;
                    nowPointX = column;
                    nowPointY = elemFromColumn;
                }
            }

            recalculatedMatrix[nowPointY][nowPointX] = minDistance;
            points[new Point(nowPointY, nowPointX)] = new Point(nowPointY, previousColumn);

            for (int i = nowPointY + 1; i < n - layer - 1; i++)
            {
                if (recalculatedMatrix[i - 1][column] < recalculatedMatrix[i][previousColumn])
                {
                    recalculatedMatrix[i][column] = recalculatedMatrix[i - 1][column] + matrix[i][column];
                    points[new Point(i, column)] = new Point(i - 1, column);
                }
                else
                {
                    recalculatedMatrix[i][column] = recalculatedMatrix[i][previousColumn] + matrix[i][column];
                    points[new Point(i, column)] = new Point(i, previousColumn);
                }
            }

            for (int i = nowPointY - 1; i >= layer; i--)
            {
                if (recalculatedMatrix[i + 1][column] < recalculatedMatrix[i][previousColumn])
                {
                    recalculatedMatrix[i][column] = recalculatedMatrix[i + 1][column] + matrix[i][column];
                    points[new Point(i, column)] = new Point(i + 1, column);
                }
                else
                {
                    recalculatedMatrix[i][column] = recalculatedMatrix[i][previousColumn] + matrix[i][column];
                    points[new Point(i, column)] = new Point(i, previousColumn);
                }
            }
        }

        static void RecountRowValues(int row, int startPoint, int endPoint)
        {
            int step = 1;
            if (startPoint > endPoint)
            {
                step = -1;
                int temp = startPoint;
                startPoint = endPoint;
                endPoint = temp;
            }

            for (int i = startPoint; i != endPoint + step; i += step)
            {
                if (recalculatedMatrix[row][i - step] + matrix[row][i] >= recalculatedMatrix[row][i])
                {
                    break;
                }

                recalculatedMatrix[row][i] = recalculatedMatrix[row][i - step] + matrix[row][i];
                points[new Point(row, i)] = new Point(row, i - step);
            }
        }

        static void RecountColumnValues(int column, int startPoint, int endPoint)
        {
            int step = 1;
            if (startPoint > endPoint)
            {
                step = -1;
                int temp = startPoint;
                startPoint = endPoint;
                endPoint = temp;
            }

            for (int i = startPoint; i != endPoint + step; i += step)
            {
                if (recalculatedMatrix[i - step][column] + matrix[i][column] >= recalculatedMatrix[i][column])
                {
                    break;
                }

                recalculatedMatrix[i][column] = recalculatedMatrix[i - step][column] + matrix[i][column];
                points[new Point(i, column)] = new Point(i - step, column);
            }
        }
        static int GetMinWay()
        {
            var minUpperLine = Enumerable.Range(0, n).Select(i => new { Value = recalculatedMatrix[0][i], Point = new Point(0, i) }).MinBy(x => x.Value);
            var minBottomLine = Enumerable.Range(0, n).Select(i => new { Value = recalculatedMatrix[n - 1][i], Point = new Point(n - 1, i) }).MinBy(x => x.Value);
            var minLeftColumn = Enumerable.Range(0, n).Select(i => new { Value = recalculatedMatrix[i][0], Point = new Point(i, 0) }).MinBy(x => x.Value);
            var minRightColumn = Enumerable.Range(0, n).Select(i => new { Value = recalculatedMatrix[i][n - 1], Point = new Point(i, n - 1) }).MinBy(x => x.Value);
            var minValues = new[] { minUpperLine, minBottomLine, minLeftColumn, minRightColumn };
            var overallMin = minValues.MinBy(x => x.Value);
            return overallMin.Value;
        }

        static List<Point> GetMinPath()
        {
            var minUpperLine = Enumerable.Range(0, n).Select(i => new { Value = recalculatedMatrix[0][i], Point = new Point(0, i) }).MinBy(x => x.Value).Point;
            var minBottomLine = Enumerable.Range(0, n).Select(i => new { Value = recalculatedMatrix[n - 1][i], Point = new Point(n - 1, i) }).MinBy(x => x.Value).Point;
            var minLeftColumn = Enumerable.Range(0, n).Select(i => new { Value = recalculatedMatrix[i][0], Point = new Point(i, 0) }).MinBy(x => x.Value).Point;
            var minRightColumn = Enumerable.Range(0, n).Select(i => new { Value = recalculatedMatrix[i][n - 1], Point = new Point(i, n - 1) }).MinBy(x => x.Value).Point;
            return new List<Point> { minUpperLine, minBottomLine, minLeftColumn, minRightColumn };
        }
    }
}
```

the minimum amount is not calculated and the path from the center to one of the sides is incorrectly searched for

Comment: but c# *has* tuples, so what exactly do you have a problem with? Note that SO is not a free code porting service. So you need to show what you have done so far, and explain what problems you have.

Comment: @JonasH I changed the post, inserted a transfer attempt, but the program incorrectly calculates the minimum amount and the minimum path

Comment: Posting an entire program with essentially "it does not work" is also not great. What is the code actually supposed to do? What is the input data? What result do you get? What result did you expect? You mention some sort of searching? But I cannot spot anything that looks like a typical graph search loop. So it is not at all clear to me what the intended behavior is.

Comment: Create programs that solve the following tasks. The input data is in a text file input.txt . The first line of the file contains the array sizes separated by a space, each of which does not exceed 20. The following lines list the array elements - integers. The result of the program should be the optimal value of the objective function and the path in which it is achieved. To specify a path, output an array by marking the elements of the path either in a different color or in some other way.

Comment: A two-dimensional numeric array of size N 1 x N 1 is given, where N1 is odd. Find a path from the center of the array to one of the sides so that the sum of the numbers along this path is minimal. It is allowed to move left, right, down or up from each cell of the array, while not returning to rows and columns that have already been visited.

Comment: That sounds like a conventional path finding problem, and the simplest solution I know of is [Djikstras algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). Typically implemented with an "open set" and a "closed set". But I see nothing in your code that resemble this. There are other algorithms, but you should at least understand whatever algorithm it is you are using, especially if you are going to pass this of as your own work.